# Geocode Yandex API не показывает номер дома

Tags: ajax, json, yandex-maps-api, api, geocode

На сайте делаю в форме адреса autocomplete и использую для подсказок Yandex API Geocode. Сам API, конечно, возвращает номера домов по запросу, но мой код не выводит в autocomplete. Подскажите где я не правильно тяну:

```
  $("#location").on("keyup", function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: '{{ url("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=my_key&format=json&geocode=") }}' + this.value,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function(data) {
      var list = [];
      $.each(data.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember, function(key, val) {
        list.push(val.GeoObject.metaDataProperty.GeocoderMetaData.text);
      });
      awesomplete.list = list;
    });
  });
```

на запрос **Гагарина** возвращаются схожие ответы, только без номеров дома. Допустим, Гагарина 200 ничего не возвращает, а просто название улицы без номера возвращаются.

Answer (score 0):

Каждый запрос в Геокодер обрабатывается как есть, если вы ищете улицу Гагарина, то именно [улицу](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=xml&geocode=%D0%93%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) вы и найдете.

Если вам нужны подсказки, то для этого нужен другой инструмент API - suggest:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest

Comment: Дело в том, что Яндекс возвращает и находит ул. Гагарина 200, но мой скрипт это не выводит. Скрипт выводит только тогда, когда ввожу название улиц без номера дома, или названия улиц с номером дома только через запятую. А без запятую не выводится. Хотя, в самом API и без запятой показывает результат.

Comment: А для чего Geocoder, если правильно будет использовать для таких целей Suggest?